# Compiling LLVM with assertions enabled and OCaml bindings

Tags: ocaml, llvm, opam

I need to recompile LLVM 3.6 locally with assertions enabled to track down a bug in my compiler (segfault when building LLVM IR), but get some errors.

1: Opam can't find LLVM lib:

```
$ sudo opam install llvm
# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lLLVM-3.6
```

but

```
$ locate libllvm | grep ocaml
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/libllvm-3.6.a
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/libllvm.a
...
```

How do I tell opam to look in a specific directory for libllvm?

**Edit**: Solved using this configure when compiling LLVM:

```
configure --enable-targets=x86 --enable-bindings=ocaml 
  --enable-debug-runtime --enable-shared
```

Comment: 1) Why don't you opam pin the llvm package? 2) maybe export CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the place for the llvm libs 3) WHY are you using sudo on top of opam?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian How would a pin help? 2) Tried CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH, problem remains. Also, opam builds with this: `--with-ocaml-libdir=/home/olle/.opam/4.02.1/lib/llvm`. I've tried to copy the libs to that location, and it actually contains `libLLVM-3.6.a`. Maybe I need to purge stuff.